# How to force gem install to download the docs file as well?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've setup the following in my ~/.gemrc file

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

so that when I do gem install some_gem, the rdocs won't get installed to not pile up my disk.

But for some gem, I'ld like to install the rdocs as well. So i tried,

```
gem install some_gem --rdoc --ri
```

the docs doesn't get downloaded. How can I force the gem install to download rdocs as well for some gem if I wnat to??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a second config file called ~/.gemrc_withdoc or something similar and include the commands to install with documentation then try the following comand

```
gem install some_gem --config-file=~/.gemrc_withdoc
```

You may even be able to get away with not creating a confile file at all and running

```
gem install some_gem --config-file=/dev/null
```

This should work as expected because gem will only use one config-file, either the one specified on the command line or ~/.gemrc. It will never use both

Answer (score 0):

`--rdoc` and `--ri` are indeed the correct options, according to `gem help install`. If it doesn't work as expected, I assume that you have to edit your ~/.gemrc every time you want to install rdocs and ri.